# Switch between front and back camera determined by accelerometer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, camera, accelerometer

I am trying to switch between front and back camera in Objective-C by using UIAccelerometer. Essentially, if the device is face up, I want the back camera to be on. If the device is face down (screen is down), I would like the front camera to be active instead. What is the best way to tackle this problem? I am accessing the camera via AVFoundation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code that might help you, created in one project of mine that uses the camera too.

This is the code of the accelerometer's delegate, where you can keep track of the device's position.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration;
{
   CGFloat x = -[acceleration x];
   CGFloat y = [acceleration y];
   CGFloat angle = atan2(y, x);

   if ( angle >= -2.25f && angle <= -0.25f )
   {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
   }
   else if ( angle >= -1.75f && angle <= 0.75f )
   {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   }
   else if( angle >= 0.75f && angle <= 2.25f )
   {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
   }
   else if ( angle <= -2.25f || angle >= 2.25f )
   {
        self.interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
   }
}
```

To see with more details, how to use the delegate, how to user declare things, etc check the code on my github:

Implementation file:
https://github.com/lucasecf/flipped-cam/blob/master/flipped-cam/LEImagePickerController.m

Project page:
https://github.com/lucasecf/flipped-cam

Comment: This is assuming you're using the camera via UIImagePickerController correct? What would the procedure be like if I created it via AVFoundation?

Comment: Yes, its using UIImagePickerController. Well, I've never used AVFoundation, so I cannot say explicit how to change the camera frrom front to back, but I believe you can user the all accelerometer code. Like I did, create a interfaceOrientation property, set the delegate in you class, start the accelerometer, etc, never forgeting in cancel the accelerometer after you dismiss/finish you view/viewcontroller.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Where exactly do you make the switch between front and back camera?

Comment: Well, in my case, there's a property in UIImagePickerController called `cameraDevice`, that you can set to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` or `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear`. As you are using AVFoundation, that would be a little different, but I think this can be easily found with google.